# I want to improve *Input System Keyboard* to fighter game | 2 Players

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

You have a better idea to improve that input system?

I've done input system like this with events, but there are many if´s i think and that is not good idea:

```
public class InputSystemKeyboard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action Left_P1 = delegate { };
    public event Action Right_P1 = delegate { };
    public event Action Jump_P1 = delegate { };

    public event Action Left_P2 = delegate { };
    public event Action Right_P2 = delegate { };
    public event Action Jump_P2 = delegate { };

    public event Action Stop_P = delegate { };


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            Left_P1();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            Right_P1();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            Jump_P1();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            Left_P2();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            Right_P2();
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            Jump_P2();
        }

        if (!Input.anyKey)
        {
            Stop_P();
        }
    }
}
```

and then in movement system y make this:

```
public class MoveSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private float speed, jumpForce;

    private InputSystemKeyboard inputSystem;

    private bool moveLeft, moveRight;

     private void OnEnable()
     {
        inputSystem = GetComponent<InputSystemKeyboard>();

        inputSystem.Left_P1 += MoveLeft;
        inputSystem.Right_P1 += MoveRight;
        inputSystem.Jump_P1 += Jump;
        inputSystem.Stop_P += StopMoving;
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        inputSystem.Left_P1 -= MoveLeft;
        inputSystem.Right_P1 -= MoveRight;
        inputSystem.Jump_P1 -= Jump;
        inputSystem.Stop_P -= StopMoving;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        moveLeft = false;
        moveRight = false;  
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        moveLeft = true;
    }
    public void MoveRight()
    {
        moveRight = true;
    }
    public void Jump()
    {
        if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
        }
    }
    public void StopMoving()
    {
        moveLeft = false;
        moveRight = false;
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (moveLeft )
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0f);
        }
        if (moveRight)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to simplify the InputSystem and try to change that structure. If you have any ideas to improve it would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: The new input system is event driven and may be what you are looking for.   [Unity Input System Package - Quick Start Guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html)  It allows easy mapping for multiple control inputs (keyboard, controller, etc) to the same event.

Comment: Questions asking for code improvement are better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because they tend to be opinionated and don't have a definite right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

For horizontal and vertical movement, there is no need of checking for every key such as WASD and arrow keys. If you go to **Edit < Project Settings < Input Manager** and expand the **axes**, you can see the input for **Horizontal** and **Vertical** are set by default for WASD and arrow keys as shown in the image below.

[image]

As `W` and `up arrow` are used to jump, clear the negative buttons in the **Vertical** section.

---

Also as you are creating a local multiplayer, right-click on them and duplicate the **Horizontal** and **Vertical** sections and name them **Horizontal1** and **Vertical1** respectively. If **Horizontal** is duplicated, remove **AD** keys from it and remove **arrow keys** from the duplicate **Horizontal1** or vice-versa. Same with the **Vertical** section also.

---

Now, all of the actions of the player using **WASD** and **arrow keys** get reduced to `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` and `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")`.

For **left** and **right** movement, you can just write:

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
```

`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` returns `1` when the positive buttons are pressed and `-1` when negative buttons are pressed.

---

For the **jump** command, you can just write:

```
if(rb.velocity.y == 0) {
    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
}
```